# Docker Playbook yml - ssh to a host with different port

Tags: ssh, ansible

I have deploy script for a Docker container.

```
- hosts: "{{ HOSTS|default('...') }}"
  remote_user: "{{ USER|default('root') }}"
  vars:
    deploy_port: "{{ DEPLOY_PORT|default(80) }}"
    git_branch: "{{ GIT_BRANCH|default('development') }}"
    python_settings: "{{ PYTHON_SETTINGS|default('development') }}"
  tasks:
  - name: Log into Docker registry
    docker_login:
      registry_url: ...
      username: ...
      password: ...
  ....
```

So firstly I do SSH to a HOSTS with user USER. But now, I have HOSTS that have different ssh port (not 22). 
How do I set this?

I try with port, and it did't work

```
- hosts: "{{ HOSTS|default('...') }}"
  port: 23
  remote_user: "{{ USER|default('root') }}"
  vars:
    deploy_port: "{{ DEPLOY_PORT|default(80) }}"
    git_branch: "{{ GIT_BRANCH|default('development') }}"
    python_settings: "{{ PYTHON_SETTINGS|default('development') }}"
  tasks:
  - name: Log into Docker registry
    docker_login:
      registry_url: ...
      username: ...
      password: ...
  ....
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a var you should set in your inventory for hosts that do not have the default port. Its name is `ansible_port` (and not `port` as you tried).

Very basically:

- Create a `host_vars` folder (at same level as your playbook or at same level as your inventory file)
- For each machine having a different port that 22, create a `<name_of_host>.yml` file in `host_vars` with the following content (replace XX with your actual port):

  ```
  ---
  ansible_port: XX
  ```

Some reference documentation:

- [Behavioral inventory parameters](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/intro_inventory.html#connecting-to-hosts-behavioral-inventory-parameters)
- [How to build your inventory](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/intro_inventory.html)